# Does NetworkInterface.GetIPv4Statistics() count internal traffic to localhost?

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I am not that familiar with networks, so I am sorry if this is a stupid question.

There is a server on which is running several modules that sends information between each other via websockets. One of the modules colects information about server including number of send/recieved bytes. It does is per server and per each process of all the modules on it. I didn't wrote any of the modules and my task is to find out why the per process size is bigger than the one of the server as a whole.

The per process uses TraceEventSession (using KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.NetworkTCPIP) and the per server uses NetworkInterface.GetIPv4Statistics(). My guess is that per process count internal traffic to other modules and per server counts only bytes that are actually send/recieved to/from outside of the server. Maybe I just don't know what to search for, but I can't find anywhere if that is the case.